# Cannot use sizeof(member variable) to initialize a static const value in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've been developing a library on a Fedora 23 box using g++ 5.3.1, and successfully building this on a Windows box using mingw (I can fetch the version here if necessary).  I handed this code off to a coworker today interested in using it.  He tried compiling it in Visual Studio 2013 (his IDE of choice), and it blew up.  Below I've created an MCVE of the problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"  // include this while in Visual Studio
#include <iostream>  // include when compiling with g++

class staticTest
{
public:
  staticTest() { };
  ~staticTest() { };

  unsigned myVal;

private:
  static const size_t staticLength = sizeof(myVal);  // errors in VS2013, compiles fine with g++ and mingw
  const size_t length_ = sizeof(myVal);  // compiles fine for all
};
```

This compiles without error or warning with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -c staticTest.cpp`.  However, in Visual Studio 2013, I get the following 3 errors about the `staticLength` assignment line:

```
statictest.cpp(12): error C2327: 'staticTest::myVal' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
statictest.cpp(12): error C2065: 'myVal' : undeclared identifier
statictest.cpp(12): error C2070: 'unknown-type': illegal sizeof operand
```

I know what the errors are basically saying, it doesn't see the member variable in the `static` context, and therefore cannot apply the `sizeof` operator to it.  Through clenched teeth, I approved changing all such instances to `static const size_t staticLength = sizeof(unsigned);` and it built fine after that.  This problem compounded even further in another instance where I tried doing something similar in a `static` function with `sizeof(memberArray)` and `sizeof(memberArray[0])`.

I'm assuming this is standard compliant, since `g++` likes it and I've heard before Microsoft compilers are loose with the standards, accepting a kind of pseudo-c/c++ language.

1. Is this bad coding style?  I always prefer using `sizeof(myVariable)` because it's more maintainable (if the type of `myVariable` changes, no changes are necessary to the `sizeof`).  Seems like to me the compiler should know (as g++ does) the type of `myVal` at compile time and not care whether it's a member of a class or not.
2. Any chance if anybody knows of a work-around for this in Visual Studio 2013, or if this problem is fixed in later versions of Visual Studio?  The real kicker for me is Windows mingw compiles this just fine, but my coworker won't budge from VS, so here I am modifying my code, making it less-maintainable, just to comply with the whims of a wonky IDE/compiler.  Oh and his final executable will be built for Linux and run on the same box as mine, so building it in VS isn't even necessary or a requirement... [angry/puking emoji]

**EDIT**
I have also tried:

```
static const size_t staticLength = sizeof(this->myVal);
```

and

```
static const size_t staticLength = sizeof(staticTest::myVal);
```

Both failed.

Comment: As for workarounds, have you tried `sizeof staticTest().myVal`? Or does that fail because `staticTest` is still incomplete?

Comment: @melpomene thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately still no good. You guessed correctly, first of 3 errors I get is `error C2027: use of undefined type 'staticTest'`

Comment: What if you move the initialization out of the class? That's allowed, right? `class staticTest { ... static const size_t staticLength; }; const size_t staticTest::staticLength = sizeof staticTest().myVal;`

Comment: @melpomene !!! Write up an answer please, that compiles for me in VS and `g++`!

Comment: Are `"stdafx.h"` and/or `<iostream>` really relevant?

Comment: @aschepler possibly not. I just piggybacked off an existing test code solution for VS which included `stdafx.h`. And I didn't know off the top of my head what header defines `size_t`, but including `iostream` made that error go away. If you know better feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in my Visual Studio compiler:

```
static const size_t staticLength = sizeof(decltype(myVal));
```

And as far as I know this should accommodate any changes to the type of myVal.

If you don't have to initialise it inside the class definition, don't initialise inside the class and have:

```
const size_t staticTest::staticLength = sizeof staticTest::myVal;
```

in a .cpp file

Comment: Using `decltype` solved this for me in 99% of my use cases, except for one different scenario in a `static` function. MS compiler can go pound sand as far as I'm concerned.